# How to get angular router NavigationError event reason?

Tags: angular, angular2-router

Is there any way to get router `NavigationError` event reason? i need different handling for this cases

- canActivate returned false
- lazy route chunk file is not found (bundles updated and i need to show proper message for user to refresh page)

Comment: Have you got a way to tackle this?

Comment: i patched angular-router-loader webpack by adding error reason (and now it's officially supported in this lib). And there is one more way, but havent test it https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12289#issuecomment-346972665

Comment: Nice! https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12289#issuecomment-301063829 helped me. Just posting here for the future reference.